# React issue applying styles when converting existing component from class-based to function-based

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having issues seeing styles getting applied from my component when converting my component from class-based to function-based component.

it is probably related to HOC issue.

So in my component, I have the styles defined as below;

```
const styles = ({palette: {somekit}}) => ({
    tabs: {
        backgroundColor: somekit.grey
    },
})
```

Earlier, it was a class-based component as below (and I could see the styles getting picked from above)

```
class MyHeader extends React.Component{}
```

However, after converting it into a function-based component as below, the styles defined above do not seem to be getting picked up.

```
function MyHeader(props) {}
```

In both the cases, I had the export defined as below;

```
export default withRouter(withStyles(styles, {name: 'MyStyle'})(MyHeader));
```

I suspect some issue with the way the component is exported above when converting from class-based to function-based.
Does this export seem proper when using function-based component ?

---Updated---
This is how withStyles is defined;

```
import { withStyles as withStylesWODefault } from '@material-ui/styles';

    import defTheme from './defTheme';
    
    export default function withStyles(styles, options) {
      return withStylesWODefault(styles, {
        defTheme,
        ...options
      });
    }
```

Comment: What styling library / provider are you using? I'm wondering whether they have an equivalent hook version for functional components rather than the HoC.

Comment: can you show the code for for your function component?

Comment: Thanks...Actually I don't have much in my functional component....Just the styles I have shown above and I use an external component <HeaderComponent> which kind of uses these styles...

Comment: I updated the question as to how withStyles is defined...Not sure if this does not support the way I have exported...